# SugarCRM - Specify field for get_entry_list

Tags: web-services, sugarcrm

I would like to receive the two fields firstname_c and email_c of an Opportunity in SugarCRM.

I tried

```
$params = array('session' => $session,
    'module_name' => 'Opportunities',
    'query' => "opportunities_cstm.external_opportunity_id_c = '".$customer."'",
    'select_fields' => array('name'=>'firstname_c', 'email'=>'email_c'),
    'order_by' => '',
    'deleted' => 0
);

$result = $soapclient->call('get_entry_list', $params);
```

BUT: select_fields seems to be ignored and I receive all fields. The only way to access the variables I need, is to use:

```
$firstname = $result['entry_list'][0]['name_value_list'][34]['value'];
$email = $result['entry_list'][0]['name_value_list'][32]['value'];
```

... which sucks, because the numbers (i.e. 34 and 32) are changing all the time.

How to fix that?

Thanks a lot,
David

PS: I also tried ...

```
'select_fields' => array('firstname_c', 'email_c'),
```

... without any success.

Comment: Which version of SugarCRM are you using and which version of the SOAP API?

Answer (score 0):

```
'select_fields' => array('field', 'field')
```

works for me, but I didn't tried with _c custom fields.

Do you receive also _c fields in soap response?

Comment: Yes, I receive the fields in the response, e.g.
[32] => Array ( [name] => email_c [value] => blabla@gmail.com )